# KDE Driver Manager does not show Nvidia drivers being installed, despite seemingly working

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, kubuntu, nvidia-prime

The KDE Driver Manager does not show my Nvidia drivers being installed. Specifically, I installed nvidia-396 through the [Proprietary GPU Drivers PPA](https://launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa). It seemed to install fine.

Reasons I have to believe the driver is installed:

- I can hear the fans booting up - this rarely happens during normal use
- `lsmod | grep -i nvidia` shows the following output:

  - `ross@1001nacht:~$ lsmod | grep -i nvidia
    nvidia_uvm            786432  0
    nvidia_drm             40960  6
    nvidia_modeset       1089536  5 nvidia_drm
    nvidia              14032896  679 nvidia_modeset,nvidia_uvm
    drm_kms_helper        172032  2 i915,nvidia_drm
    drm                   401408  10 i915,nvidia_drm,drm_kms_helper
    ipmi_msghandler        53248  2 nvidia,ipmi_devintf`
- nvidia-settings launches, and [clearly shows under 'PRIME profiles' that the Nvidia GPU is being used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hlwNb.png).
- Lastly, I tested the GPU by running Left 4 Dead 2 via Steam, ensuring all graphical settings were set to their most demanding options. The laptop had no problem, so the driver is clearly installed and working.

Laptop specs

- OS: Kubuntu 18.04.1
- Host: Inspiron 7577
- DE: KDE
- CPU: Intel i5-7300HQ (4) @ 3.500GHz
- dGPU: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050 Mobile
- iGPU: Intel Device 591b
- memory: 1580MiB / 7842MiB

I would like to assume this is just a bug related to Driver Manager, but I'm fairly certain it shows nvidia-390 (recommended driver before installing the ppa) as installed when it is so, leading me to think maybe there is something more at play.

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you figure out if this is just the driver manager being buggy?

Comment: I actually don't use KDE or Ubuntu anymore, but I did hear elsewhere though that this has been a long-time bug and it doesn't seem to be getting worked on.

Comment: Ah that sucks. And I really don't get the reasoning. Such bugs leave bad impressions, which in turn may lead to less popularity and donations. And while I like KDE so far I have seen a ton of bugs and crashes while configuring it. If you don't mind answering, what do you use now?